# If $\tan(\alpha)=2-\sqrt{3},$ find the value of the acute angle $\alpha$

Tags: trigonometry

I rewrote it as $$\tan\left(2\cdot\frac{\alpha}{2}\right)=\frac{2\tan(\frac{\alpha}{2})}{1-\tan^2(\frac{\alpha}{2})}=2-\sqrt{3} \ \Rightarrow \ 2(1-\tan^2(\frac{\alpha}{2})-\sqrt{3}(2\tan(\frac{\alpha}{2}).$$ Obviously, it didn't bring the answer. My other attempts also were untrue. I would like somebody to hint at other method(s).

Comment: You need to look at $\tan(2\alpha)$ instead.

Comment: @franzlemmermeyer I have tried it, $$\frac{2\tan(\alpha)}{1-\tan^2(\alpha)}=\frac{4-2\sqrt{3}}{1-4+4\sqrt{3}-3}=-\frac{2-\sqrt{3}}{3+2\sqrt{3}}.$$ I evaluated the answer via the calculator and compared the result with the output of $\sin15^\circ,$ they weren't the same! So, I think that this also doesn't work. What do you say to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should pay more attention to your hints.

$\tan \alpha = 2-\sqrt{3}$

Since we are given that $\alpha$ is acute and $0 < \tan \alpha < 1$, then 
$0 < \alpha < \frac{\pi}{4}$ and $0 < 2\alpha < \frac{\pi}{2}$.

Since \begin{align}
   \tan 2\alpha
   &= \dfrac{2\tan \alpha}{1 - \tan^2 \alpha} \\
   &= \dfrac{4-2\sqrt 3}{1 - (7-4 \sqrt 3)} \\
   &= \dfrac{4-2\sqrt 3}{-6 + 4 \sqrt 3} \\
   &= \dfrac{2(2 - \sqrt 3)}{2\sqrt 3(2 - \sqrt 3)} \\
   &= \dfrac{1}{\sqrt 3} \\
   &= \tan \frac{\pi}{6}
\end{align}

Then $\alpha = \dfrac{\pi}{12}$

Comment: Could you explain how you got $\sqrt{3}$ after multiplying out the brackets in this expression $$\frac{2(2-\sqrt{3})}{2\sqrt{3}(2-\sqrt{3})}?$$

Comment: Because the numerator had $2 - \sqrt 3$, I guessed that the denominator did too. Then I worked backwards from there. I could have multiplied by $\frac{2+\sqrt 3}{2 + \sqrt 3}$ and simplified but that looked like work.

Comment: Note. If $\tan 2\alpha = \tan \dfrac {\pi}{6}$, then $2 \alpha = \dfrac {\pi}{6} + n\pi$.

Answer (score 2):

**hint**

Put $$\beta=\frac {\pi}{2}-\alpha $$

then
$$\tan (\beta)=\frac {1}{2-\sqrt {3}}=2+\sqrt {3}$$
and
$$\tan(\beta)-\tan (\alpha)=2\sqrt {3}$$
hence

$$\tan (\beta-\alpha)=\sqrt {3}=\tan(\frac {\pi}{3}) $$
and

$$2\alpha=\frac {\pi}{2}-\frac {\pi}{3}=\frac {\pi}{6} $$

Done!

Comment: Could you explain how $$\tan(\beta)-\tan (\alpha)=2\sqrt {3}$$ and $$\tan (\alpha)\tan (\beta)=1$$

Comment: @Tug'tekin Look now. i edited.

Answer (score 1):

Just it's better to know that $\alpha=15^{\circ}$ and the rest is smooth:

$$\tan15^{\circ}=\tan(45^{\circ}-30^{\circ})=\frac{1-\frac{1}{\sqrt3}}{1+\frac{1}{\sqrt3}}=\frac{\sqrt3-1}{\sqrt3+1}=\frac{(\sqrt3-1)^2}{2}=2-\sqrt3$$
and since you want an acute angle, we are done!

Comment: or we get $$\frac{\pi}{12}$$

Comment: @michaelrozenberg Could you explain why you raised the numerator to the second power and how you got 2 in the denominator: $$\frac{\sqrt3-1}{\sqrt3+1}=\frac{(\sqrt3-1)^2}{2}?$$

Comment: @Tug'tekin It's $\frac{\sqrt3-1}{\sqrt3+1}=\frac{(\sqrt3-1)^2}{(\sqrt3+1)(\sqrt3-1)}=\frac{3-2\sqrt3+1}{3-1}=2-\sqrt3$.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg One more question: now I see that you multiplied both sides ($\tan(15^\circ)=\frac{\sqrt3-1}{\sqrt3+1}$) by $\frac{\sqrt{3}-1}{\sqrt{3}-1},$ but will not doing this change the value of $\tan(15^\circ)$ because you also multiplied $\tan(15^\circ)$ by that expression? ($\tan(15^\circ)(\frac{\sqrt{3}-1}{\sqrt{3}-1})$)

Comment: @Tug'tekin No. I did not do it. I multiplied the nominator and the denominator of $\frac{\sqrt3-1}{\sqrt{3}+1}$ by$\sqrt{3}-1$. See please my solution better.

Answer (score 1):

$$\csc2A-\cot2A=\dfrac{1-\cos2A}{\sin2A}=\cdots=\tan A$$

Here $2A\equiv60^\circ\pmod{360^\circ}$

Comment: Another indirect way : $$\cot A+\tan A=2\csc2A$$   If $\tan A=2-\sqrt3,$  $$\cot A=?$$